# Swift - How to return a bool closure

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, closures, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to write a function that returns a Bool:

```
func registerForPushNotifications() -> (Bool) -> Void {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        [weak self] granted, error in
        return { granted }
    }
}
```

But I get this Error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Void' to return type '(Bool) -> Void'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1- Your function doesn't return `Bool`, it returns a closure that takes a `Bool` as a parameter and returns `Void`. 2- `return { granted }` is called inside a closure that's defined to return `Void` not `Bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function return type is weird. I think what you're trying to do is get a callback with the result for whether or not the device is authorized to receive push notifications.

You should change the following:

```
func registerForPushNotifications() -> (Bool) -> Void {
   // Your implementation
}
```

to

```
func registerForPushNotifications(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [weak self] granted, error in
      completion(granted)
   }
}
```

This way, you can call `registerForPushNotifications` with a closure you wish to run after push permissions have been determined.

```
registerForPushNotifications { granted in
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it seems we need @escaping before completion: